# Cannot sign Click Once manifest with code signing certificate via VS options or using signtool

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce

I have a C# Visual Studio 2013 solution (FindAlike) consisting of a number of projects. One of these projects (SimilarFiles) is a class library, including an AddIn Express component, as it implements an MS Office Add-in. When I publish the project as a ClickOnce installer an MS Add-in, a folder is created in the projects Publish folder with the version number of the project containing many files with extension .deploy. Also in the folder above are a file called findalike.application and one called setup.exe. If I copy the contents of the Publish folder to a new machine I can install the MS Add-in by clicking on findalike.application, but I receive a warning about an unknown publisher. If I confirm installation it proceeds satisfactorily.

I have a valid code signing certificate purchased from Comodo, which I use successfully with SignTool to sign a Windows Forms self-extracting installer from another project in the solution.

The option to sign the ClickOnce Manifest in the SimilarFiles project is greyed out, presumably because SimilarFiles is a class library project.

I can specify a code signing certificate by right-clicking on  the SimilarFiles project and  hovering over the Add-in Express entry and then selecting Signing Options, but the warning message still appears when I attempt the installation on a new machine

How can I use the code signing certificate in order to indicate to the ClickOnce installer on the new machine that the manifest is signed?

Signtool does not work on the setup.exe file, stating that it is not a valid Windows executable. Neither does it work on findalike.application

Answer (score 0):

There is a Signing area on the VS Publish form which I'd missed. If I browse for my Code Signing Certificate (.pfx extension) and select SHA-1 only it signs OK, and install proceeds without warning. Thanks to Add-In Express for this solution.